# How to send model from view to controller with HttpUtility.HtmlEncode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I want to send model's description from view to controller. But it is throw exception special character's warning again. I want to use HttpUtility.HtmlEncode in view without [ValidateInput(false)] in controller. It is possible ?

```
@model  UserModel
@using (Html.BeginForm("CreateUser", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.TextAreaFor(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(x => x.Description))

    <button type="submit" id="btnCreate">Create</button>
}
```

Comment: seems like you are trying to enter html string into textarea and passing it to controller, which is bad approach. i would like to suggest there are many text editors are available. just you needs to plug their js and css for that CKEditor i found is best solution in your case

Comment: how to use @Html.TextBoxFor(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(x => x.Description))

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add `[AllowHtml]` attribute in your model ?

```
public class ViewModel
{
    [AllowHtml]
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

No, it isn't security bug. `ASP.Net MVC` has automatic HTML encoding. `Razor` also includes the `Html.Encode` method. Calling this method will be double-encoded. Therefore you can not use Html.Encode twice.

Comment: I know your answer. But is it security bug ?  I want to use HttpUtility.HtmlEncode in View .